# What is the difference between two dimensional array parameters?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Here , I can declare a two dimensional array like this

```
int dp[105][140000]
```

or like this

```
int dp[140000][105]
```

When I work with this arrays , I see a significant time difference between first and second one.First one is way faster then 2nd one. Why is that?
for example this code I was running

```
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
    for(int k=1;k<60;++k)
    {
        int x = (~fact[k]) & ((1<<17)-1);
        for(int s=x;s;s=(s-1)&x)
        {
            if(dp[i-1][s]+abs(A[i]-k) < dp[i][s|fact[k]])
            {
                dp[i][s | fact[k]] = dp[i-1][s] + abs(A[i]-k);
                dpchoosen[i][s|fact[k]] = k;
                dptracer[i][s|fact[k]] = s;

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Cache. Elements that are processed next to each other should be laid next to each other in memory.

Comment: I don't see why cache would necessarily work better or worse for either case. The array members are laid out sequentially either way.

@weak_coder , I think you need to give at least some basic details on what you're actually doing with the arrays to give people a chance to answer your question well.

Comment: "When I work with this arrays..." - *What Work?*. Post the code.

Comment: question is unclear and more information should be provided...

Comment: What's `n`??? What's `fact`? How do you manage to use the same code with both array declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the difference is related with that in the second one there are done more calculations to determine the offset of a row. 
My assumption is based on that the calculation of the address of a row is more compound than the calculations of the address of an element inside the row.
In any case you should see what assembler code is generated by the compiler.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just a uint*uint+uint operation in both cases? i.e. the number of bits in the numbers involved will be the same?

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie It depends on the code used for testing. For example the inner loop could simply increse the pointer in a row. That is there would be calculated only the addresses of rows.

Comment: I am still not getting it, it will still be uint+uint in both cases, even more, the number of multiplications and additions will be the same.

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie If you calculated the address of a row you can simply use the (C++/C) increment operator for the pointer. You need not do any other calculations. At least the multiplication operator will not be used.

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie I updated my post that it would be mpore clear what I want to say.